# PCI passthrough stopped working in (K)ubuntu 20.04 guest, but only after login

Tags: kvm, qemu, kubuntu, pci-passthrough

I have been using KVM/QEMU for GPU passthrough successfully for over a year now. In my case, I was passing an GTX1070 to linux and an AMD RX480 to Windows. When my Arch installation got messed up, I switched to Ubuntu server 20.04 and set it up with the same configuration. That was working fine for a few days, until suddenly the Kubuntu guest (using the 1070) booted to a black screen. I had foolishly forgotten to install ssh server on the guest, so I could not ssh in, and just deleted/recreated the VM.

This time, using either GPU, I got the same problem with a fresh installation. With the AMD GPU, the Kubuntu splash screen would show on the GPU-connected monitor, but then goes black as soon as the login screen appears. With the NVIDIA GPU, there is no visible response.The AMD GPU still works fine with my Windows guest.

When I run `lspci` from Kubuntu guest, both cards show up. I'm wondering if an update caused this to break, so I will try with other distros and see if I have the same issue. But in the meantime, has anyone experienced a similar issue?

Edit: With a fresh Ubuntu 20.04 installation, things seem to be normal, so it must be Kubuntu-specific. Could there be a Kubuntu-specific update that is causing this?

Edit2: It seems I spoke to soon. After the initial boot with Ubuntu 20.04, the GPU screens go black after login (but the login screen does appear on them). My next step is to try something 18.04 based.

Edit3: I tried installing an Ubuntu 18.04 guest as well. When booting with the AMD GPU, the login screen appeared on the GPU-connected monitor, but the system was frozen. After changing the XML to what used to work for the NVIDIA, I was in the same situation as before: I could boot the guest, the guest could detect the NVIDIA card and confirmed that it was using the NVIDIA driver, but the connected displays were not detected as show by `xrandr`

Edit4: Got the NVIDIA card working under Ubuntu 18.04 after updating/upgrading, installing nouveau drivers (instead of the nvidia-driver-440 I tried previously), and deleting spice-related stuff from the XML file. Now to wait a few days, as Kubuntu seemed fine for a few days before I lost graphics.

Edit 5: Well after about a week, the Ubuntu 18.04 installation died in the same way as Kubuntu did. VM runs, screen stays black, VM will not accept a clean shutdown signal and does not respond to ssh.

I am going to give up on this host installation and try again with clean install.